# Are VMWare pefromance metric IDs stable?

Tags: .net, monitoring, vmware, vsphere

I am monitoring VMWare vCenter hosts and VMs using VMWare's .NET SDK. I am using the metric **[key](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50/vim.PerformanceManager.CounterInfo.html)** as a key in a database. How stable are those keys? I could not find any word about it in the documentation. Do they change depending on VMWare/vSphere version? Or with each restart of the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do that, these keys do change — at least between versions. You want to use the string keys, like `mem.consumed.average`, and map them to keys for each host using `PerfCounterInfo[] PerfManager.perfCounters`.

Comment: Learned it the hard way myself :/